# yadcf cumulative_filtering not filtering previous column?

Tags: filtering, yadcf

http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/cumulative_filtering.html

If you begin with selecting "Tag 5" in the last column, the first column is not filtered to the only remaining selections (you get all values as selectable)

Is this a one way cumulative? (col1 first, then col2 then col3), or should the cumulative affect all other columns in the process forward and backward?

test case link here - https://jsfiddle.net/myc05td2/

Select `Tab 2` in the last column, and `Some Data 11` is still available in the first column.

Or, select `Tab11` and you will see that it should only list `Some Data 11` in the first column, but it shows all items in column 1

Comment: seems like a bug, cause if you check the fourth column, you'll see that its values are reduced properly unlike the first column filter

Comment: has been reported in git, but their rules say to also report here so I did... hopefully it will be fixed

Comment: Actually I prefer questions to be asked on SO only, and bug to be reported on GitHub, in this case I'm still not 100% sure if its a bug, anyway, please post a link to jsfiddle so I can check what went wrong there, p.s, I'm the author of the plugin

Comment: @Daniel also provided the link in github - https://jsfiddle.net/myc05td2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the reason,

You had an explicit `cumulative_filtering: false` for the first column, while the global was set to `true`.

Once I removed that explicit false, the problem was solved

```
{
    column_number : 0,
    filter_type: "multi_select",
    select_type: 'select2',
    cumulative_filtering: false
},
```

jsfiddle sample: https://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/2aLntwkf/

Here is the complete code:

```
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';

    
    oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
    
    yadcf.init(oTable,
        [
            {
                column_number : 0,
                filter_type: "multi_select",
                select_type: 'select2'
            }, 
            {
                column_number: 3,
                filter_type: "auto_complete",
                text_data_delimiter: ","
            },
            {
                column_number : 4,
                filter_type: "multi_select",
                select_type: 'select2',
                column_data_type: "html",
                html_data_type: "text",
                filter_default_label: "Select tag"
            }
        ],
        {
            cumulative_filtering: true
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: This was your demo page, so I am glad it was that easy.  I appreciate your time

Comment: my bad :), for some reason the usage example not in sync with the source code